# Simplifying small code example

Tags: python

Lets pretend I have the following code.

```
num1 = 33
num2 = 45
num3 = 76
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for item in lst:
    if item == 'one':
        print num1
    elif item == 'two':
        print num2
    elif item == 'three':
        print num3
```

Is there a way to make this more elegant when there is no correlation between the list and the print sentence? Meaning, is there a way to get rid of the ifs and elifs?

Comment: what's your code really about? no requirement, no coding.

Comment: What should your code do if the element doesn't match any of the if clauses? As you have written it, it just ignores that element. Is that intentional?

Comment: I was just wanted to see if there was some kind of bad as pythonic way of looping through the list and the numbers.
In the end, I guess a dictionary might be the best way.

Yes, it's intentional. I know all the different possibilities, so I don't need an else that picks up the rest, since there will be none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course use a dictionary, to look up the response:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
resp = { 'one': num1, 'two': num2, 'three': num3 }

for item in lst:
  print resp[item]
```

This is still pretty static, though. Another approach would be object-orienting it, so you get to implement a function in the objects in `lst` that makes the decision.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> tups = ('one', 33), ('two', 45), ('three', 76)
>>> for i, j in tups:
    print(j)


33
45
76
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it intentional that your code ignores objects that are not mentioned in any if/elif clause? If so, use a dictionary with a default value of 'None' if the object is not found:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
d = { 'one': 33, 'two': 45, 'three': 76}

for item in lst: 
    x = d.get(item)
    if x is not None:
        print x
```

Comment: I guess you meant `if x is not None`

Comment: Oops, thanks! That's why it's a good idea to test all code, even if it is extremely simple!

Answer (score 2):

the whole logic of your if/else is equivalent to a dictionary's key and value pairs

```
d = {"one":33, "two":44, "three":76}
```

this part of your code

```
if item == 'one':
    print num1
```

is the same as

```
print d["one"]
```

like wise for the others

Answer (score 1):

If you have dictionary like this:

```
d = {"one":33, "two":44, "three":76}
```

You can print it like this:

```
for k in d.keys():
    print d[k]
```

This presumes that you do not care about the order.

Answer (score 1):

For your simple example a dictinary lookup poposed in other answers is the best. But sometimes you need to run completely different code for each condition, so the following idiom might be useful too:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def process(self, item):
        # Select the method to call based on item value
        return getattr(self, 'do_'+item)()

    def do_one(self):
        # do something here

    def do_two(self):
        # do something other here

    # ... other methods ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When there's no correlation between the if clause and the prints, you can create a mapping dictionary to store the correlations.  You need to be careful to map to the variable of numx, not the current value (thus the use of the eval function):

```
num1 = 33
num2 = 45
num3 = 76
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']

map = {'one': 'num1', 'two': 'num2', 'three': 'num3'} 

for item in lst:
    print item in map and eval(map[item]) or 'Unknown'
```

If you're sure the item is in the map, the last line can be simplified further to:

```
    print eval(map[item])
```